# Tables in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

How do I create a Table Layout in Visual Basic 2010 with the "Grid.class"? When ever I search for grid class tutorials I always end up with data grid ones. I am trying to create a table where I can add rows that have their own views.

Comment: You are referring to this [`Grid`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Have you included WPF in your search term? Here is one: http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html

Comment: Thank you sooooo much @TimSchmelter I didn't think of adding wpf to the search term.